# A sentence from The Economist that I don't understand

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence from the magazine [*The Economist*](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2018/07/12/worker-shortages-could-heal-americas-economy) that I don't understand.

> Fully 5.8m more Americans are in work than in December of that year, when the Federal Reserve began raising interest rates. *That is two-thirds as many as lost their jobs during the Great Recession.*

The italicized sentence is the one that confuses me. Shouldn't it be "That is two-thirds as many as those who lost their jobs during the Great Recession?"

I hardly believe The Economist made a mistake in that sentence. Can anyone tell me why the sentence is correct as it is and, if there is any, what words might have been omitted from that sentence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*The Economist* did not make a mistake.

This sentence is short for

> That is two-thirds as many [Americans] as lost their jobs during the Great Recession.

[*The Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/many) explains this:

> ***Much, many, a lot, lots:* without a noun**
>   *We usually leave out the noun after much, many and a lot, lots when the noun is obvious.*

Looking in dictionaries, it appears that some classify *many* in this usage as a pronoun and some as an adjective.
For example, the *Cambridge Dictionary* has the following example sentence under the adjective definition of *many*:

> Not everyone could get a seat, and many were unhappy with having to stand,

while the *OED* has the following example under the pronoun definition:

> To most people he was only one knave of many.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the "missing" "those who".

Comment: @Keepthesemind: The words "those who" don't belong in the sentence. Let me think about how to address this.

Answer (score 0):

> **as**2 Adverb
>
> 1.1 Used to emphasize an amount.
>
> 'as many as twenty-two rare species may be at risk'

[OOD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as)

Looks proper to me.

**EDIT**
Mitch, you are right.  The *two-thirds as many as lost their jobs* is an amount. So the phrasing "as many as" is used in the OP's sentence to call attention to this amount.  Two-thirds is not insignificant. Therefore the usage by The Economist looks proper to me.

Comment: This needs a lot more to be an answer. Just a link to a definition doesn't explain. Then again, the OP is not explicit about what exactly they don't understand in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Fully 5.8m more Americans are in work than in December of that year, when the Federal Reserve began raising interest rates. That is two-thirds as many as lost their jobs during the Great Recession.

This is perfectly grammatical and natural, as most Economist articles should be.

Apparently, the difficulty some non-native speakers have with this kind of comparative construction arises from the fact that the comparative clause lacks its subject as here.

> That is two-thirds as many as [_____ lost their jobs during the Great Recession].

The comparative clause is noted with the bracket and the lacking subject with the blank.

This sentence compares 'that' (5.8m) with the number of Americans who "lost their jobs during the Great Recession" by saying this:

(1) 'That' is x many;

(2) y many lost their jobs during the Great Recession; and

(3) x = (2/3)*y; y = 8.7m

Since you're comparing x with y, you can't repeat 'y many' as the subject of the comparative clause.

> *That is two-thirds as many as **Americans** lost their jobs during the Great Recession.

OR

> *That is two-thirds as many as **8.7m Americans** lost their jobs during the Great Recession.